# Make [ask] link to ../help/how-to-ask instead of ../questions/how-to-ask

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I just realized that there are two versions of the How to Ask page. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is in Help Center. The [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) is accessible somewhere through the Questions button at the top of each page and can be linked to in comments using `[ask]`. It is also the less detailed and arguably less to-the-point version of the two.

Sure, the Help Center version might be considerably longer but it provides very good advice to people on exactly what goes into writing a good question. The Questions version, on the other hand, contains just some very basic guidelines that IMO aren't all that useful, especially given the sorry state of question asking in this day and age.

As Cody Gray pointed out, it would be nice to add a Search box to the Help Center version of the page, even though there is a prominent Search link.

I therefore propose changing the version of the How to Ask page that `[ask]` links to.

Comment: Definitely in favor of this change, I hate having to use the long version and the one you want to change it to is a lot better imo.

Comment: Let's add a big inline "Search" box to the new How to Ask page, too.

Comment: ... and pretend people will use it.

Comment: @Bolt Are there any usage stats on the search box on the current page?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Both links go to the same page now?

Comment: Use [ask] for great judgment.

Comment: The problem described here **can no longer be reproduced**, as both linked pages provide the same text. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

Comment: There is a 'status completed' tag, though.

Comment: @Anthon this was completed already in 2016, as you can see from the history. Why in the world would it be voted to close as off-topic in the year 2017, when it was clearly on-topic an needed?

Comment: @eis I give you a hint. He might live under a bridge.