# Help center links in comments should include "how-to-ask" option

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, help-center

This feature for [comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) is really useful:

> - `[help]`, `[help/on-topic]`, `[help/dont-ask]`, `[help/behavior]` and `[meta-help]` – link to frequently visited pages of the help center. Link text is "help center" (capitalization is respected). All links point to the main site.

Please include `[help/how-to-ask]` (["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) in this list.

It's a great page that often would contain the reason (and help) for new users not familiar with the system yet.

Comment: Use `[ask]`, which goes to [ask]. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255766/215552

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ohh aha. And it's even on the comment-formatting help page I mentioned - 50% confusing help, 50% me not paying attention IMHO. Thx for the tip!

Comment: I had no idea these short cuts existed. Was just searching for how to format links properly.